# Is this a normalisation error?

Tags: database, database-design

This is similar to my last question, but it sort of boils down to the problem more really.

I'm designing a system to schedule tasks; most of the time recurring tasks.  For example, a user can schedule "sweep the floor" to occur Monday, Wednesday and Friday every week.

I can tell from the schedule whether a task is due to be done on any particular day, and most importantly I can tell if it is due to be done on the current day.  I then have to display this list of current tasks to the workers (and send it to handsets around the site).

The user then indicates that they have started the task (so we need a state Task-Started) and when they have completed a task (Task-Worked).  If the worker has not done the job very well, someone inspecting the task can "Fail" it, going to the ending state Task-Failed.  A task can have some other states too, but that should be enough for the scope of this question.

What I'm wondering is if I should create the **instance** of each task occurrence in the database, thus allowing me to store **state** against **that particular instance** of the task.  I suppose another way of looking at it is I'm creating the initial state of "Due" in the database, or "Due-Today" along with the actual DateTime it is Due (or at least the DateTime of the Window of Opportunity to do the task).

However - this state can **always** be derived anyway as that's where I'd generate "today's" task list from, so it does feel like a normalisation error - it feels like I'm repeating data that can be derived anyway.

Pros:

- It would allow the generated "Due" task to have an exact Date-Time, thus shielding it from changes to the schedule that should only affect future days (though granted my Schedule-History table allows me to get at the old data).
- The schedule for that particular day could be tweaked, just in case something extraordinary is happening that day.
- It creates a formal state in the database rather than deriving it (did I just make that up?).

Cons:

- It would need a background process to generate these instances (or generate the "Due", or "Due-Today" state, depending on how you look at it).

I guess my problem comes down to this:

1) If the Schedule was just a list of exact Date-Time's, there would be no problem as each entry describes the task itself.  It is the fact: This Task at This Date-Time.  And once that Task is complete, we store the fact against it.

2) A Recurring Schedule however just describes when each Task should be, rather than describing the actual occurrence.

I hope that makes some sense.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do separate "task" and "task instance", but don't generate new instance when task is due.

Generate it when it is started (and leave the end time and the success status as NULL). When the task instance is finished, replace these NULLs with concrete values.

So, no need for a background process, yet you can always determine when:

- due task is not started (no row in the instance table)
- or started task has not been finished (NULL end time)
- or how successful is the finished task (by examining the success status of a task instance whose end time is non-NULL).

Comment: Thanks Branko (and thanks for your answer on the other question too).  I'm slowly working it all through, so not ignoring the answers - I'll respond more later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would model this as **task schedule**, which would contain information like which days the task occurs on and when it is next due.

As a background job each day, you will look at the schedules and determine if they occur today.  If so, you will create a **task** record, and update the next due date.  Next due date is a denormalisation, but I think it makes life easier.  It depends how complicated your scheduling logic becomes and how much data you have.

The task table is a child of task schedule.  The task table would contain the date due, status, assigned to, etc.  At the same time you would send these tasks out to the handset (I would do this in a second job kicked off when the first completes successfully).

Comment: Yes this was basically the other way I was thinking of doing it, though I would not store the next due date as it is a trivial query to find that value, plus it would conflict if the schedule changed (which is of course one of the reasons to avoid denormalisation).  Thanks :-)

Comment: I have a similar problem and I've decided to store the next due date.  In my case it's complicated due to public holidays, months with different numbers of days and manual edits.  I didn't want to recalculate the next date for every item every day.  If it's simple, don't store it.

Comment: Yes that does sound more complicated.  But don't you need to calculate it anyway to be able to store the next due?  Just curious.

Comment: Yes, but it only needs to be calculated once per execution rather than once per day.  If the next run is in 30 days I don't need to calculate it on the 29 days inbetween just to find out it's not time yet.  Also, can index the next date to make the morning batch run that creates the tasks from the schedules quick.